# Laravel - how to calculate the sum of objects in an array in blade view

Tags: php, laravel

I have a foreach loop in a blade view, where I am listing the objects that have a pivot property price:

```
                @foreach($transaction->options as $option)
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <p>Option description: {{ $option->description }}</p>
                      <p>Price: {{ $option->pivot->price }}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                @endforeach
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4>Options total: </h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

I would like to since I am doing a foreach loop here, calculate the sum of all the options so that I could write it next to `Options total:`

I have tried with this:

```
               @foreach($transaction->options as $option)
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <p>Option description: {{ $option->description }}</p>
                      <p>Price: {{ $option->pivot->price }}</p>
                      @php($total += $option->pivot->price)
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                @endforeach
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4>Options total: {{ $total }}</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

But, that didn't work, I got an error:

> Undefined variable: total

How can I do this?

Comment: This is something you should be doing in your controller or domain logic and passing it to the view, it shouldn't be the view's job to calculate information.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Define the variable first:

```
@php($total = 0);
```

You can also get sum of pivot column with:

```
$transaction->options()->sum('price')
```

Comment: Oh, didn't now we could get the sum directly from a relationship with this method, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Blade has a `@php` directive to execute a block of plain PHP within your template. Be aware that this may be a sign of bad design, and you should avoid put much logic inside your template. Ie:

```
@php
    $total = 0;
@endphp

@foreach ($items as $item)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->code }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
</tr>

@php
    $total += $item->price;
@endphp

@endforeach

....

<p>Total {{ $total }}</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do the calculations in the blade template. This can be helpful for other users. Just do the calculation inside blade syntax {{ }} and use the display:none; css property.  For example

```html
<div style="display: none">
 {{ $total = 0 }}
</div>
@foreach($report as $device)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$device->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$device->price}}</td>
        <div style="display: none">{{$total += $device->price}}</div>
    </tr>
@endforeach
<tr>
    <th>Total Distance Travelled</th>
    <th>{{$total}}</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily by saying

> {{$transaction->options()->sum('price')}}